# Delete 500 million documents from a mongo collection containing 18 billion documents

Tags: mongodb

We are trying to do some cleanup from a mongo collection which has 18 billion documents and we need to remove around 500 million documents out of them. Despite using an indexed query to cleanup the data in batches of 1000 each and using bulk operation, I find the execution being painfully slow. Could someone please help with a strategy to do such cleanup? I am happy to provide more information if needed.

We are using a Scala process comprising of 8 threads, each handling a batch of 1000 to do the cleanup.

Comment: Small batches and indexes is what I was going to suggest. Is your hardware simply not up to the task? Do you know what is taking all time? Is it pagefaults?

Comment: I have checked the swap space and it is unused. On checking the free memory on the host, it has got 100G of cached memory which can be used up when required. It doesn't seem to be a memory issue by the look of it and seems to have something to do with the way mongo executes the delete operations.

The host I am currently running this on has a spinning disk but I haven't seen a considerable speed up happening on ssd's either.